# Oracle find all tables that have specific columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find all tables in my database that have two columns `LOCATION` and `ASSET_ID`

So I tried this :

```
select owner, table_name, column_name
from all_tab_columns
where column_name in ('LOCATION','ASSET_ID');
```

the problem is this query give all tables that have `LOCATION` or `ASSET_ID` not both of them.

so I changed it to this :

```
select owner, table_name, column_name
from all_tab_columns
where 1=1
and column_name ='LOCATION'
and column_name = 'ASSET_ID';
```

it shows 0 result.

Please help.

Comment: Of course the first one gives you OR, and the second one gives you no answers - what did you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select all the rows as in your initial attempt. Then group by `owner` and `table_name` and keep only those that have TWO rows returned  in the initial query. Use the `having` clause for that:

```
select   owner, table_name
from     all_tab_columns
where    column_name in ('LOCATION','ASSET_ID')
group by owner, table_name
having   count(*) = 2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a couple of subqueries factored as common table expressions and a join, as in:

```
WITH cteLOCATION AS (SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
                       FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
                       WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'LOCATION'),
     cteASSET_ID AS (SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
                       FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
                       WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ASSET_ID')
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
  FROM cteLOCATION
  NATURAL JOIN cteASSET_ID
```

This is one of the very few situations where I'd ever use `NATURAL JOIN`.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9036b/2)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using joins (similar to @BobJarvis' https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984132/754550 but more traditional without with - clause):

```
select a1.owner,a1.table_name
from all_tab_columns a1, 
    all_tab_columns a2
where a1.owner=a2.owner
    and a1.table_name=a2.table_name
    and a1.column_name='LOCATION'
    and a2.column_name='ASSET_ID'
order by a1.owner,a1.table_name
```

or using sets:

```
    select owner, table_name
    from all_tab_columns
    where column_name='LOCATION'
intersect 
    select owner, table_name
    from all_tab_columns
    where column_name='ASSET_ID'
order by owner, table_name
```

or using 'group by' clause as already posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981174/754550 by @mathguy

```
select owner, table_name
from all_tab_columns
where column_name in ('LOCATION', 'ASSET_ID')
group by owner, table_name
having count(*)=2
order by owner, table_name
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY table_name) cnt
          FROM all_tab_columns a
         WHERE column_name IN ('LOCATION','ASSET_ID')
         ORDER BY table_name)
 WHERE cnt = 2
```

Comment: sql has a 'having' clause to avoid such nesting of selects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981174/754550